# HTTP error 422 in authentication responses

Tags: bentley-itwin

I have get an error for response 422. May i know how can i resolve this?

class FormsAPI:

```
def __init__(self, key):
    self.authorization_key = personal_forms_authorization_key

def getFormInformation(self, formID):
    '''
    Get forms details.
    return: list_form details
    '''
    url = 'https://api.bentley.com/forms/'
    print(url)
    try:
        params = {'id': formID
                }
        headers = {'Accept': 'application/vnd.bentley.itwin-platform.v1+json',
                   'Authorization': self.authorization_key}
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
        print(response)
        if(response.status_code == 200):
            content = jsonParser(response.text)
            list_FormDetails = content
            return list_FormDetails
        else:
            return "error"

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

list_FormDetails = FormsAPI.getFormInformation(formID)

Answer (score 0):

See answer from laurynasr for same question at https://github.com/imodeljs/imodeljs/discussions/1626:

> 422 is returned from the Forms API, not as part of the authentication -- it means that the client provided some parameters that could not be processed. The response payload contains more details.